# How to download a file of a htaccess protected domain without prompts?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to download this file for example:

```
http://somedomain.com/backups/archive.zip
```

That domain is htaccess protected. Is there a way to pass the password and the user via the URL? I want to be able to download that file without any prompts.

Possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax:

```
http://username:password@somedomain.com/backups/archive.zip
```

- This will send the user credentials in the standard HTTP "Authorization" header.